# C# [.NET 3.5] Multi-Threading and Bitmaps - Different/Inconsistent errors

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, image-processing, bitmap

I am using C# on .net 3.5 (Cannot use higher versions)

I have an implementation of a Blocking Queue that implements the Producer-Consumer pattern loosely based on http://element533.blogspot.com/2010/01/stoppable-blocking-queue-for-net.html

I have 4 files in the same namespace:

1. File0 contains the main function and starts two threads for func1
   and func2 and instantiates an object of the above queue
2. File1 has func1 that splits a video into individual frames of images      (Bitmaps) and enqueues them to the above queue. If all items are added, it
   signals that it has completed adding to the queue. Acts as the Producer
3. File2 has func2 that checks if there are items available in the queue and then dequeues the first element. Acts as the Consumer
4. Contains the implementation of the queue

Important bits of code

func1

```
        for (int index = 0; index < numFrames; index++)
        {
            Bitmap oneFrame = videoReader.ReadVideoFrame();
            ImageProcessor.frameQueue.Enqueue(oneFrame);
            oneFrame.Dispose();
        }
```

func2

```
while (!ImageProcessor.frameQueue.isCompleted())
            {             
                using (Bitmap image = ImageProcessor.frameQueue.Dequeue())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Height: " + image.Height);
                    Console.WriteLine("Width: " + image.Width);                    
                }                
            }
```

Whenever this runs, func1 runs as expected but func2 throws different types of errors when it tries to access image.Height. Some of the errors that I have seen are

1)

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Additional information: Object is currently in use elsewhere.
```

2)

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred 
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

3)

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Additional information: Parameter is not valid.
```

Any guesses what I'm doing wrong? Can I not use multi-threading with bitmaps?

I have a feeling that the issue could be in the oneFrame.Dispose() in func1

Comment: oneFrame.Dispose() is drastically wrong, you must delete that.

Comment: if this is for Windows and you Bitmaps have window handles (so they are GDI based having device context not just memory map) then YOU CAN NOT USE THEM OUTSIDE MAIN WindProc THREAD. If you do it will invalidate WinAPI (just like any other visual component call outside main thread would) usually nothing wrong is happening at first but after a while you got random access violations and crashes on unrelated WinAPI or GDI calls. Sometimes it take few minutes sometimes just seconds ...(last tested on Win XP so newer versions can behave differently)

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch:

Try placing it outside of your using statement:
Instead of this:

```
        using (Bitmap image = ImageProcessor.frameQueue.Dequeue())
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Height: " + image.Height);
            Console.WriteLine("Width: " + image.Width);                    
        }
```

Try This:

```
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap((System.Drawing.Image)ImageProcessor.frameQueue.Dequeue());             
                Console.WriteLine("Height: " + image.Height);
                Console.WriteLine("Width: " + image.Width);                    
            image.Dispose();
```

**EDIT**

```
bool IsComplete = false;
while (!(IsComplete = ImageProcessor.frameQueue.isCompleted())) 
            {             
                using (Bitmap image = ImageProcessor.frameQueue.Dequeue())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Height: " + image.Height);
                    Console.WriteLine("Width: " + image.Width);                    
                }                
            }
```

Comment: @user3243571 - see my edited code - basically construct the bitmap from the image of the dequeud frame.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. I have a feeling the problem could be in the oneFrame.Dispose() in func1

Comment: @user3243571  I just re-noticed - you are using a blocking queue
It might be blocked in your while statement , 
Reassign the variable each iteration:
bool IsComplete = false;
while (!(IsComplete = ImageProcessor.frameQueue.isCompleted()))

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `oneFrame.Dispose();` from **func1**. It is being marked for disposal right after being queued. It looks like **func2** is consuming the disposable object and will attempt to dispose it anyway when it exits the `using` block.

Edit: One thing to keep in mind is if **func2** doesn't work its way through all the objects you created, you'll have undisposed objects hanging around. In the producer/consumer model, it is the consumer's responsibility to take care of what is produced.

Comment: I did the same thing and it works. However, when it has to process a very large number of frames, this seems to cause issues later down the road. Essentially func2() contains more than just printing the height and width so it takes a while to process each Bitmap whereas func1() is super fast.

Comment: You don't have anything that restricts the upper limit of items. You might consider checking the queue size after you've added something to the queue in func1(), and force it to wait until it's below your maximum.

Comment: Yep that is exactly what I decided to do after observing this behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: Although I already have the consumer waiting on the producer to place items in the queue. Now I need to get the producer waiting on the consumer to remove items from the queue. Deadlock here I come!

Comment: You should have no issue as long as you guarantee that isCompleted() will return true in func2() when func1() signals. If isCompleted() continues to return false even after it's finished, func2() will be waiting forever.